# Error "No authenticationScheme was specified" error when trying to access protected api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I'm building my api using .NET 7 and I use the bearer token as authentication. However, when I decorate the controller with the [Authorize] annotation I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was
> specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default
> schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string
> defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action
> configureOptions).    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext
> context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)
>
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Authorization: Bearer
> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6IjMxNzY5ODIxMDAwMTEwIiwibmJmIjoxNjg4MTI2MTIyLCJleHAiOjE2ODgxMjk3MjIsImlhdCI6MTY4ODEyNjEyMn0.9bcifi4phO3m8cZacOhQtX_YZuro8N2QHFcNlmJafSY
> Connection: keep-alive Host: localhost:44308 User-Agent:
> PostmanRuntime/7.32.3 Postman-Token:
> e88e6bec-0828-4272-a7f4-af11947b3ffd

my Program.cs file

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Logging.AddDbLogger(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Logging")
    .GetSection("Log").GetSection("Options").Bind(options);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(o =>
    {
        o.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Vision API");
        o.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

my Startup.cs file

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddResponseCompression();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<VisionContexto>(
                opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("VisionContexto"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Vision.Dados")));
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Configuracoes:ChaveSecreta"));
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer("bearer", x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });
            services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
                .AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerGenOptions>();

            services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
            {
                options.ReportApiVersions = true;
                options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                options.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersion.Default;
                options.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new MediaTypeApiVersionReader("x-api-version"), new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"));
            });
            services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
            {
                options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
                options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.OperationFilter<SwaggerDefaultValues>();
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                    new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
                    {
                        Title = "Vision API",
                        Version = "v1",
                        Description = "Vision Web API",
                        Contact = new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiContact
                        {
                            Name = "Vision",
                            Email = "app@prodadosinformatica.com.br",
                            Url = new Uri("https://www.prodadosinformatica.com.br")
                        }
                    });
                c.DocInclusionPredicate((_, api) => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.GroupName));
                c.TagActionsBy(api => api.GroupName);
                string caminhoAplicacao =
                    AppContext.BaseDirectory;
                string nomeAplicacao =
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
                string caminhoXmlDoc =
                    Path.Combine(caminhoAplicacao, $"{nomeAplicacao}.xml");
                c.IncludeXmlComments(caminhoXmlDoc);
            });
            services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerGenOptions>();
            services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
               .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
               .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
               .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
               .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("VisionContexto"),
               new SqlServerStorageOptions
               {
                   CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                   SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                   QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                   UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                   DisableGlobalLocks = true
               }));
            services.AddHangfireServer();

            services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(options => options.CompatibilityMode = PasswordHasherCompatibilityMode.IdentityV2);

            services.AddOptions();

            services.Configure<Configuracoes.Configuracoes>(Configuration.GetSection("Configuracoes"));

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
              options =>
              {
                  var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                      {
                            new CultureInfo("pt-BR"),
                      };

                  options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "pt-BR", uiCulture: "pt-BR");
                  options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                  options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
              });

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                        description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                }
            });
            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseCors(x => x
              .AllowAnyOrigin()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

I've been there for several days and I still can't find the solution. Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you have to replace `"bearer"` with `"oauth2"` when calling  `AddJwtBearer`

Comment: @Philippe did not work

Comment: This Startup is massive. I would start with a new api project and add a controller. And then try the authorise attribute. If it doesnt work early you can ask a more specific question. If it works you can add you code until it fails and you get the cause of the error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand why you have a `Startup.cs` file in your `.Net 7` project. Why don't you configure services and middleware in `Program.cs` file?

Comment: Is your endpoint working without the attribute? A lot of times I ran into this error was when ASP.NET couldn't map the request path (e.g. a version variable was wrong in the path)